# Question of the Week #42

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post #42 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com).

## But WAIT!  What happened to post 41!

I messed up and didn't get it up in time.  So I selected my own question of the week :P

I'm collecting together 42 tops questions/answers found on SU so add any that you feel really rock.

> Please post any questions that you feel is of worth and the reason
> why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's
> sake. We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those
> selected in the [Super User
> Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If
> you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to
> post about a question and its contents.
>
> When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in
> writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into
> consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we
> can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be
> something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have
> somebody interested in writing the article.

Comment: +1 because of reasons.

Comment: And how will you record that the post was at 42 points, it's easy for anyone to change it after its posted.

Comment: @TomWijsman - Just include a screenshot in the post.

Comment: [lop lop lop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6998364#6998364)

Comment: I'm just adding comments, because @Kronos made me do it!

Comment: Check [Fake Programmers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116/fake-programmers) yourself if you don't believe me